# Crawling play store in core php

Tags: php, android

I would like to know whether there is any way to crawl the google play store using package url in core php. I want to get the app rating and icon of the particular package url from the play store.

Can anyone help me to do this..??

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://42matters.com/api/lookup They have an open source api that should return just about anything you want and return it in a JSON format.  It also has an iOS part as well if you want to crawl that as well!

After you register on the website you will be provided with an Access Token.  You need this to build your requests.  To get the data on an specific package name, you build the link as this: 
https://42matters.com/api/1/apps/lookup.json?access_token=?&p= 
NOTE: It must be the PACKAGE NAME, not the title of the app, for example, the package name of Clash of Clans is com.supercell.clashofclans.  You can obtain the package name by performing a search through their website as well. That link would be built as such: 
https://42matters.com/api/1/apps/search.json?access_token=?q=  Where query would be clash of clans! 
If you use Google Chrome, give PostMan a try, its great for testing API's!

Hopefully this helps you out, if you need anymore help, let me know and I'll be glad to help you!

Comment: I checked the link but it just gives demo. In that link They will return the details of the package name given. I need to accomplish it

Comment: I updated my original answer to give you some more information on it! Hope that helps you some, if you need anymore help Let me know!

Comment: I have registered in that site but i didnt get any access tokens. 
I got a mail for activating my account which contains a link.